# MSAccess Query Not Refreshing After Update

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have simple table subform with 2 pulldown comboboxes. The challenge I'm having is that even though I've carefully mapped parameters to the subform's query driven table will NOT populate with data. I have made sure to have the "me.requery" event (after update) for each combobox pulldown.

```
Combobox 1 = [cmb_opt_verified]
Combobox 2 = [cmb_srv_capture_status]
```

The comboboxes are within a subform, that is embedded in to tab control, that is embedded into the parent Form

[image]

Where

1. Is the parent form
2. Is the subform
3. Is combobox 1
4. Is combobox 2
5. Is a table that is powered by a query with the combobox parameters mapped to it.

The table query has the subforms combo-box parameters mapped with respect to the subform's table. The expected result is a list from the application of combobox 1 AND combobox 2 user selection.

[image]

```
[Forms]![Server Data Workbench]![srv_AML_detail].[Form]![cmb_opt_verified]
[Forms]![Server Data Workbench]![srv_AML_detail].[Form]![cmb_srv_capture_status]
```

I've tried leaving the form running and switching between pulldown options, but not luck. The query is not updating at all even with refreshes. I am able to see the list if I hard code into the query either options from combobox 1 and combobox 2

Is there a way I can determine if the values that are in the comboboxes are truly making it to the query? Or is there something I'm missing in the mapping of the comboboxes to the form and query?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Command would be `Me.Requery` not `requery.me`. Post your actual code. What is combobox RowSource? Fields are text data? Database is SQLServer? I don't use dynamic parameterized queries. I prefer VBA to apply criteria to form Filter property.

Comment: The requery.me was a typo. I actually have me.requery in my code. Nice try though

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassing.. my combobox was bounded to the wrong column. I fixed it by writing in a msgbox [forms]![blah]... and it displayed the recordID and not the text itself. Problem resolved. It's strange how in some cases the bounded column is right while in other cases it's wrong. guess it's MSAccess way to keep you on your toes - or the product is very buggy.

Comment: I suspected that could be case and was why I asked for combobox RowSource. Nothing 'buggy' about it. If you don't want to sort/filter with recordID then why include it in RowSource?